# Using nullable integer to access array

Tags: c#, arrays, types, integer, nullable

I am trying to implement a binary search tree in C#, and following Cormen et al chapter 12 to do it. To do this I need to use nullable types, like this:

```
 public int insert(Node newNode) // return array index of added node
    {
        int? y = null;
        int? x = this.root;

        while (x != null)
        {
            y = (int)x;
            if (newNode.key < this.tree[x])
            { }

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Now I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. 
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)?

For this `if (newNode.key < this.tree[x])`  line.
Is it illegal to use nullable types to acces an array index?
Can I initialize the array maybe in a different way to allow it?
Or should I forget about null and use -1 for instance?

Comment: refer to [`Nullable` types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) and try `x.Value` after ensuring it is not null.

Comment: If you want to really learn data structures & algorithms I would suggest doing this exercise in an unmanaged environment.

Comment: @aj.toulan: Why?  Most if not all common algorithms can be implemented just fine in a manged environment.  As a benefit, you get to focus on the actual algorithm without also worrying about correctly managing memory.

Comment: I do not get why this question gets a -1. The MSDN documentation is not explicit about whether or not a nullable int can be used to access an array index so I think it would be legitimate question. If I was not here to learn I obviously would have not asked the question...

Comment: I'm not sure why they gave you a -1. But to answer your question, a nullable type in .net is really just a struct with two components, the implemented type data (in this case an int) and a bool that says if the data is valid. The implementation of array simply knows nothing of what a nullable int is and won't know what to do with the value if it's null. Personally, I'd rather my code brake that does the conversion than have some exception get thrown that says, this value was not set. It forces the programmer to think more about what it is that they want. In the end it reduces technical debt.

Comment: @EricJ. Doing your own memory management is pretty essential for learning not only data-structures, but computer science. C# will let you control whether your data is stored by value or by reference, by choosing a struct or a class. Using classes has more overhead because they're handled as reference types. Trying to time, analyze and compare two algorithms is pointless at that point. It's hard to tell if the garbage collector or your algorithms implementation is taking more time in one algorithm than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `x != null` constraint in place, all you need is `this.tree[x.Value]`.

And it's not clear what `y` is for but I doubt that you need or want that `(int)` cast. Also, it matters what the types of `tree[x]` and `newNode.key` are.

> Is it illegal to use nullable types to acces an array index?

Yes

> Can I initialize the array maybe in a different way to allow it?

No

> Or should I forget about null and use -1 for instance?

That depends. Both are viable when done correctly.

Comment: The cast was there as I was trying some things to get that error fixed. Indeed it is not needed, and it is not working now.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'.

You are trying to compare an int? to an int.  The compiler is essentially saying "what should I do with this comparison if the int? is in fact null.  That's a question the compiler cannot work out, so you will have to provide that logic.

In other words, since you already guarded against x being null, use

```
this.tree[x.Value]
```

Answer (score 0):

check the variable if it `HasValue` if exist use the `Value`

```
public int insert(Node newNode) // return array index of added node
    {
        int? y = null;
        int? x = this.root;

        while (x.HasValue)
        {
            y = x;
            if (newNode.key < this.tree[x.Value])
            {
               //your logic here
            }

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `x != null` and `x.HasValue` are exactly the same thing.